# Pupetter - can't find ID of a <input> form

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I'm stuck with an issue :
In a `form` i got an `input` field that goes:

```html
<input type="text" name="st100972" value="0" class="ibro_sb" maxlength="2"
```

I wanna use puppeteer to fill it and i wanna use :

```js
  await page.waitForSelector('st100972');
  await page.$eval('st100972', el => el.value = '3');
```

I can't find it's ID, but I can't edit the code, how do I can find it?

Comment: It has no id attribute , so it has no id

Comment: @JonP than how can i get ID to work for my pupetter to add id to it everytime i start a new browser?

Answer (score 1):

`waitForSelector` does what it says. You need to provide it with a valid selector, which you haven't.

Use `await page.waitForSelector('[name=st100972]');` then read up on css selectors